# Angular.js form submit action missing?

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I copied an old form to a new site, old form is working but the new form is not, I don't know what's missing.

```
The old form is at : http://nmjava.com/gate/Contact_Information.html
New form is at : http://gatecybertech.com/Contact_Information.html
```

I know HTML, but don't know Angular.js, I know when a submit button is pressed, the action in the form is called, but in my case it looks like this:

```
<form  name="form"  id="form" Method="post" class="form-horizontal" ng-hide="submitDone == true" ng-submit="onSubmit(form.$valid)" novalidate="novalidate">
```

After I looked into the code on that page, I can't find where "onSubmit(form.$valid)" is happening, I guess there must be some function that handles it, but where is it ?

Comment: There will be a script or more than likely a `.js` file that will be a controller and in there will be a function declared `$scope.onSubmit = function(formValid) .... ` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is an `MVC` framework, A.K.A `Model, View, Controller`. The view in this case is the UI (HTML), the model contains the *business logic*, for example state management or AJAX calls,
and the controller reacts to the view in order to get data from the model, to send back to the view.

there can be many views, controllers and models.

Angular parses the html for `ng-*` *directives* (as well as other, custom directives) and attempts to traverse the `controller`'s scope in order to evaluate the property's value, in this case `onSubmit(form.$valid)`.

In order to find the correct controller that contains your function,
you should consider the following:

1. Angular controllers are attached to a view using the `ng-controller` directive. An HTML element containing this directive will have its scope point to the controller specified in that directive's property value (`ng-controller="mainCtrl"`), and all child elements will have access to that scope as well.
2. Angular has scope hierarchy, meaning your code can be in any of the nested controllers which are parent elements of your `ng-submit`.
3. Angular also has a global scope, dubbed `$rootScope`, which can be accessed from within any part of your view, as well as controllers if the `$rootScope` dependency is injected into them.

So, in short, your function is in in one of the controllers. Using the above points you can narrow down the *scope* (no pun intended) of your search to one of the relevant controllers, usually found in a `controllers` folder in your application.